# Why does Vec::retain run slower after updating to Rust 1.38.0?

Tags: performance, rust

After updating Rust to version 1.38.0 from 1.36.0, I noticed that my program runs slower — by about 50%.

Using `perf`, I discovered that half of the program time is spent in `alloc::vec::Vec<T>::retain` in the new version. In the older version, this function does not even show up. Why would `retain` take so much longer in 1.38.0?

The call to `retain` is done like this:

```
some_vec.retain(|&x| x < DEADLINE);
```

`deadline` is a constant `u32` and `some_vec` is a `Vec<u32>`.

I ran the program without the `retain` calls in both versions. In this case, 1.38.0 was still slower on average, but only by ~10% instead of the > 50% seen before.

To recap what happened in the tests:

**Version 1.36.0**

- with `retain`: ~18sec
- without `retain`: ~11sec

**Version 1.38.0**

- with `retain`: ~28sec
- without `retain`: ~12sec

For a reproducible example, you can try:

```
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let start = Instant::now();
    let mut my_vec: Vec<u32>;
    for _ in 0..100_000 {
        my_vec = (0..10_000).collect();
        my_vec.retain(|&x| x < 9000);
        my_vec.retain(|&x| x < 8000);
        my_vec.retain(|&x| x < 7000);
        my_vec.retain(|&x| x < 6000);
        my_vec.retain(|&x| x < 5000);
        my_vec.retain(|&x| (x < 5) & (x > 2));
    }
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    println!("Program took: {:?}", duration);
}
```

With `cargo +1.36.0 run --release` and then `cargo +1.38.0 run --release`.

For this small example, I got:

```
$ cargo +1.36.0 run --release
Program took: 4.624297719s

$ cargo +1.38.0 run --release
Program took: 8.293383522s
```

Comment: I believe this should be [reported to the Rust lang team](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues).

Comment: Thanks for improving your question in response to feedback. You really turned it around! I hope you get an answer.

Comment: I did a little digging: 1.37.0 is fast like 1.36.0; nightly is slow. The generated MIR of 1.37 and 1.38 look the same to me if you disregard the comments and relative ordering of functions, which implies either: rustc changed the number / order / kind of LLVM passes, or the version of LLVM used by rustc changed between 1.37 and 1.38, in which case this is an LLVM regression as well as a rustc regression. I don't know how to tell which, unfortunately.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65970) is the bug report that @Miguel filed

Answer (score 2):

In general, [rust.godbolt.org](https://rust.godbolt.org) is useful for checking quality of the generated code (but don't forget to add optimization flags!)

In your case code generated for `retain` has clearly changed for worse: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/ZhVCDg

So you should [report that to Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues) as a performance regression.

Comment: I've already reported it to rust as @Peter Hall suggested as well.

Comment: For the curious: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65970